# Javascript window.open() passing args

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to use `window.open()` to pass along some arguments to another page.

I want the page to be

```
myPage.html?img=1.jpg
```

Where once on that page I will use javascript to get the arg and show the image.

However I cannot figure out how to do this with window.open() cause it says the pages does not exist which I can understand.

```
 window.open('myPage.html?img=1.jpg','_blank')
```

Hope this makes sense and I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: what result did u get with your example? did it work?

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then myPage.html must actually not exist!  Either that, or due some permissions issues, it can't appear.  Simply go to myPage.html in your browser and see if you can load it.  I'm willing to bet that you can't.

Comment: Do you mean a new browser window is openned, but it does not display the page ? If so, is the URL in the new browser window right ? Or it not what you expect ?

Comment: Yeah silly I had spelled it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

myPage.html should exist, 
and **check the docs on window.open**

to pass vars:

```
var variable = "lol";
var w = window.open("http://example.com");
w.variable = variable;
```

or yopu can visit the opeing window:

```
var variable = window.opener.variable;
```

Comment: This code snippet is not working for Microsoft Edge browser. How can we pass args in case of Edge?