# Open a URL using window.open and passing data to it?

Tags: javascript, html

Honestly, I just want to know if something like this is even possible.

Let's say I used `window.open("https://twitter.com/");` and I navigate to twitter. Is it possible to pass data to that page?

For example, to put data into a text field on that page? Is it possible to get the elements of that page by their ID the same way would you by using `getElementById('')`?

Is doing something like this even allowed? I can't seem to find anything means of accomplishing something like this.

Comment: Have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643036/javascript-window-open-passing-args?rq=1

Comment: The answer is a flat out no (unless you own the code on the page you are opening, as the OP in @Magicprog.fr's post does). You cannot run code on a page that does not belong to you. [That is called cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), it is a major security vulnerability, and you should be glad browsers use the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) to prevent it.

Comment: As a caveat: you can of course pass data to a page you don't own, such as in @Magicprog.fr or by using a GET request style URL. However, you have to way to make the other page actually do anything with that data

Comment: @MatthewHerbst that was what I was thinking honestly. Thank you.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I'm not 100% following that post from @Magicprog.fr 

`var variable = "lol";
var w = window.open("http://example.com");
w.variable = variable;`

What exactly is this doing? Does the var `variable` refer to an element on the page `http://example.com`?

Comment: Just look at the API... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var t= 'sss';
  window.open('http:www.twitter.com?id=78&otherdata='+t)
</script>
```

Like this way you can pass your data to url and then get it using GET request style URL.

Comment: Would I replace`otherdata` with the ID of the fields I want to put the data into?

Comment: you can use any other name instead of `otherdata`. i just want to tell you that how you can send more than one things to the url using `&`.